# Trying to convert int type to string type

Tags: java, string, object, methods

First time posting. If I have two variables named x and y and they both are holding an int value; is it possible to convert the value they are holding into a string type? I am doing some school work and it's part of a class file names MyPoint. Here is the exact instruction:

"A method named toString that returns the values of the x and y in the following String format:(x,y)"

Can any body point me in the right direction? I keep getting errors saying that it is incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a int to a string using:

```
Integer.toString(number)
```

or

```
String.valueOf(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about your problem, the code should look something like this:

```
public String toString(int x, int y){
    return "(" + Integer.toString(x) + "," + Integer.toString(y) + ")";
}
```

When 1 and 3 are passed into the method as parameters, "(1,3)" is returned.

This uses the Integer.toString(number) method.

EDIT:

As pointed out by @dave, you can also just use

```
public String toString(int x, int y){
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

Comment: Or even just `return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways:

1. `String.valueOf(x)`
2. `"" + x`
3. `Integer.toString(x)`

Try like,

```
public String toString(int x, int y){
    return (Integer.toString(x) + "," + Integer.toString(y));
}
```

or,

```
public String toString(int x, int y){    
            return (String.valueOf(x) + "," + String.valueOf(y));    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Integer.toString(numberX + numberY); //Convert integer values to String
```

or

```
String.valueOf(intX + intY); //Convert some values type to String
```

or

```
String str = "" + X + "" + Y; //Convert integer values and adds to text message
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the format() method:

```
public String toString(int x, int y){
    return String.format("(%d,%d)",x,y);
}
```